# wheelchart around exploded slices of a pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was wondering whether it is possible to code a wheelchart around exploded slices of an initial pie chart. My code so far produces a pie chart with the relevant slices exploded and an awkward little separate pie chart floating around it. Ideally, interpersonal violence and collective violence would wheel around the categories ''Government & Social'' and ''Emergency''.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 

\begin{document}

\hspace{6cm}\begin{minipage}[l]{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small] 

\pie[pos ={1, 2}, 
explode={1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
text=pin, hide number,
    color = {
    blue!40!,
            red!40,
        violet!40!}
]{
9.3/Collective Violence (95.6\%),
2.9/Interpersonal Violence (4.4\%)
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
     \hspace*{0cm}

     \begin{minipage}[r]{0.09\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
 \noindent
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\pie[pos ={1, 2}, 
explode={0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
text=pin, hide number,
    color = {
        blue!40!,
        blue!60!,
        red!60, red!70,
        blue!70,
        red!40}
]{
12.2/Government \& Social (12.18\%),
5.4/Emergency (5.40\%),
20.1/Budget \& Debt (20.07\%),
17.3/Infrastructure (17.26\%),
11.0/Business \& Industry (11.04\%),
8.8/Necessities (8.84\%),
6.9/Health (6.89\%),
18.3/Multisector \& Others (13.08\%)
}
\label{fig:}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \newline
    \raggedright
\footnotesize{\textit{Text}}

\end{document}
```

I sketched my vision below, in the hope it may help you visualise what I mean exactly.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks,
Leslie

[image: The vision]

Comment: The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package may be helpful. The documentation has examples of this sort. Also, please post a minimal working example of compilable code (including `\documentclass`)

Comment: Dear @mbert. Thank you very much for your answer, you are completely right, I forgot to add the packages. I edited the working example into a compilable entity. I have already inspected the wheelchair package (page 7 looks particularly promising for my purposes), however I was not able to make it work (not even the working example, I am afraid). Do you think the pie-chart package could perform the same functions as the wheelchart package or would you switch packages all together?

Answer (score 1):

A pie diagram is a bad lying way to represent data. Worse is a exploder pie diagram. -and unforgivable is a diagram with extra slices, where area loses all meaning.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[
pos={0.05,-0.1},
explode={1, 1},
hide number,
color={blue!40!, red!40},
text opacity=0,
]{
9.3/Collective Violence (95.6\%),
2.9/Interpersonal Violence (4.4\%)
}
\pie[
explode={0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
text=pin, hide number,
color={blue!40!, blue!60!, red!60, red!70, blue!70, red!40},
font=\small,
]{
12.2/Government \& Social (12.18\%),
5.4/Emergency (5.40\%),
20.1/Budget \& Debt (20.07\%),
17.3/Infrastructure (17.26\%),
11.0/Business \& Industry (11.04\%),
8.8/Necessities (8.84\%),
6.9/Health (6.89\%),
18.3/Multisector \& Others (13.08\%)
}
\node[font=\small, pin=-20:{Collective Violence (95.6\%)}] at (3.8,1) {};
\node[font=\small, pin=20:{Interpersonal Violence (4.4\%)
}] at (3.1,2.4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Exploded pie diagram with extra pies in the background]

Answer (score 1):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The percentages are automatically computed and can be used with `\WCperc`.

In the key `slices style` we use `\WClistcolors` which refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

In the first `\wheelchart`, the first and second slice are shifted with the key `explode{1,2}=0.5`. For the first slice there is no line by using the key `lines{1}=0`.

The second `\wheelchart` is positioned with the key `at`. The `data` and the `lines` are determined by the keys `data angle shift{list}` and `lines angle shift{list}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  anchor ysep=40,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCvarB{} (\WCperc),
  lines,
  perc precision=2,
  slices style={\WClistcolors,draw=black},
  start angle=0
}
\wheelchart[
  data sep{1}=1.5,
  explode{1,2}=0.5,
  lines{1}=0,
  pie,
  WClistcolors={blue!40!,blue!60!,red!60,red!70,blue!70,red!40},
]{%
  12.18/Government \& Social,
  5.40/Emergency,
  20.07/Budget \& Debt,
  17.26/Infrastructure,
  11.04/Business \& Industry,
  8.84/Necessities,
  6.89/Health,
  18.32/Multisector \& Others%
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(12.18*1.8:0.5)},
  data angle shift{list}={-14,-6},
  lines angle shift{list}={-12,0},
  radius={3}{4},
  total angle=12.18*3.6,
  WClistcolors={blue!40!,red!40}
]{%
  95.6/Collective Violence,
  4.4/Interpersonal Violence%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Came her again to try to use your package(the manual looks most impressive). -but you have already done it.